# Share pdf/webpage from safari into app using share extension in objective c

Tags: objective-c, safari, share, ios8-share-extension

i have successfully added my app into safari share view (along with Facebook,twitter and other apps) on tapping share button using share extension. But now my question is how can i share content(pdf/webpage data) directly into app.

Please help me out.

Comment: Did you found Any Solution?Help me if you found solution as i m also looking for the same